# Error installing embedded Visual Service Pack 4 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-7, embedded, installation

I'm having error installing embededd visual C++ 4.0 Service Pack onto Windows 7 machine so I wonder if anyone has successfully installed it.  I already installed visual studio 6, visual studio 2005 and 2008, and they seem to work fine, but after installing eVC++ then creating project with it, there is no SDK platform available for me to choose, so I exit out the IDE and installed SDK platforms for WinCE.  Then went back to create project again, it's still the same problem, no SDK platform available for me to choose.  Then next I installed eVC SP4, but it failed during installation.  I uninstalled eVC and SDK platforms that I previously installed then reboot the machine.  I install eVC again as administrator and eVC SP4 too, but eVC SP4 fails again during the installation.  Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is the ambiguity on the Microsoft's website, which I came across, and I believe you came across.In particular eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0 SP4 (~60 MB) available on [Microsoft's website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16683), is just an update to the presumably pre-installed package. You need to install the main package first (~300 MB), that is,

1. Install the main package - available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/EMbeddedVisualC4.0)
2. Install the update to SP4 - available on [microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=16683)

P.S. If you happen to be interested in the PPC 2003 emulator, which requires at least these two packages, you can find my detailed instructions on [Retrocomputing.Stackexachange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14604)

Answer (score -2):

i too had the same problem.. When i contacted microsoft they asked me to refresh registry and try. and this worked for me.. I hope this will solve ur problem too.

Just use register doctor or some good registry softwares to do it,.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Refresh registry? that sounds scary because I don't want to mess thing up on my machine.. But I will do further research on your suggestion.

Comment: Its not a big issue. But needed a little care to be taken while doing it

Comment: It'd be great if you could add the instructions for 'refreshing the registry', presumably you need to delete specific keys or subtrees.